# Redirect user to specific CMS page upon registration?

Tags: cms, ce-1.9.1.0, redirect, customer-account, register

I would like to make Magento redirect the user to a specific CMS page right after s/he submits the account registration form. Something like a "thank you" page for having registered.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25711352

You need create observer:

```
customer_register_success
```

And redirect to cms or where you want

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a simple extension for this ([learn how to create simple extension](http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/magento-hello-world-module-extension/)) where you are going to observe the `customer_register_success` event.

In your observer file **Namespace/ModuleName/Model/observer.php**

```
<?php 
class Namespace_ModuleName_Model_Observer
public function myredirection(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $AccountController = $observer->getEvent()->getAccountController();

        $Customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

         $response1 = Mage::app()->getResponse(); // observers have event args

            //set any url you want
            $url = Mage::getBaseUrl().'cms-page'; //'http://www.example.com/';
            $response1->setRedirect($url);
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->sendResponse();

        return;
      }
```